# Display icon from the local resources in a form window with C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, icons

I'm not sure if I'm missing something. I need to display a simple .ico file on my Windows Form in VS2010. I created a PictureBox on the form but when I go to its properties and select the .ico file in the `InitialImage` it tells me that I can't use it. It used to be so simple to do this with C++ ...

So how do I do this in a .NET C# project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

InitialImage is display while main image is loading. And if you need to set the main image you have to set Image property of the picture box.

but Icon can't set as `InitialImage` or `Image` directly so you can convert Icon to Bitmap by code as below

```
pictureBox1.Image = Resources.Icon1.ToBitmap();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [ToBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.tobitmap.aspx) function of the Icon object? Load up the ICO file into the Icon class and then just invoke this method - and you'll have a bitmap that is usable on the PictureBox.

Comment: Thanks. I can set it in the code. I thought it would be helpful to do it from the resource editor. It'd be nice to see the icon while I'm positioning it in the form.